# Multi row insert fail

Tags: postgresql, insert, multiline

I'm using PostgreSQL 7.4.19. Why can I not use a basic SQL statement as INSERT?
I am running online examples (from the blog ['Faster INSERT for Multiple Rows'](http://kaiv.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/faster-insert-for-multiple-rows/)):

```
create table things (things_id serial primary key, thing text);
insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 0'),
('thing nr. 1'),
('thing nr. 2'),
('thing nr. 3');
```

When I run it, it yields:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 0'),
                                                         ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do a `select version();` from inside `psql` or run `psql --version` to check which PostgreSQL version you're using.

Comment: Works for me in 9.0 and 9.1. There must be something you are not showing us.

Comment: I'm guessing my service provider is running a version of PostgreSQL too old for this sort of thing (7.4.19). Looks like I need to just have a lot of insert statements for the time being.

Comment: The first version supporting this syntax is [8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/release-8-2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on PostgreSQL 9.0 , What your PostgreSQL Version?

```
skytf=> create table things (things_id serial primary key, thing text);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "things_things_id_seq" for serial column "things.things_id"

NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "things_pkey" for table "things"
CREATE TABLE
skytf=> \d things
                               Table "skytf.things"
  Column   |  Type   |                         Modifiers                          
-----------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------
 things_id | integer | not null default nextval('things_things_id_seq'::regclass)
 thing     | text    | 
Indexes:
    "things_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (things_id)

skytf=> insert into things (thing) values ('thing nr. 0'),
skytf-> ('thing nr. 1'),
skytf-> ('thing nr. 2'),
skytf-> ('thing nr. 3');
INSERT 0 4

skytf=> select version();
                                                      version                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.0.1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48), 64-bit
(1 row)
```